# Yii - remove index.php from url - always redirected to 'index.php'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii, url-rewriting

In my test application, I'm trying to remove `index.php` from the url. I can access the root page like so `http://localhost/trackstar/` instead of `http://localhost/trackstar/index.php`, but as soon as I'm trying to access another page like `http://localhost/trackstar/project` or any other page I'm always ending up at the `index.php` page. Opening `http://localhost/trackstar/index.php/project` works however.

I'm using WAMP server. Configuration as below.

Rewrite module in apache is enabled.
Config `main`:

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',            
        'rules' => array(
            'commentfeed' => array('comment/feed', 'urlSuffix' => '.xml', 'caseSensitive' => false),
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ),
```

`.htaccess` in root folder of project:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I've also added in `httpd.conf`, although not really necessary I think:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/TrackStar/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've tried several combinations of extra parameters in `.htaccess`, but I keep getting redirected to my `index.php` page.

Any thoughts as to why this doesn't work?

**Edit:**

Since I'm being redirected, the checks in `RewriteCond` don't succeed, in other words the `REQUEST_FILENAME` isn't found as a directory or file. Maybe there's something off in my directory structure?

[image]

The `TrackStar\protected\views\project` directory, for example is the page I'm trying to access via `http://localhost/trackstar/project`. My `Yii` framework files are in a directory above the `www` folder.

Comment: Does your urls get generated properly? Or application redirects you to index.php?

Comment: @PeterM: my browser says `http://localhost/trackstar/project` but I'm on the `index.php` page.

Comment: Is .htaccess located in the same directory with index.php?

Comment: @CreatoR: Yes, in `www\Trackstar`, there is another `.htaccess` file located in `www\Trackstar\protected` with contents `deny from all`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add into .htaccess following after `RewriteEngine on`:

> ```
> RewriteBase /trackstar/
> ```

The problem in: when not found file it redirects to `http://localhost/index.php`, in request `http://localhost/trackstar/index.php/project` file `index.php` is found and it works correctly

UPDATED:
Try modify your urlManager settings (add `/trackstar/`):

> ```
> 'urlManager' => array(
>     'urlFormat' => 'path',            
>     'rules' => array(
>         'commentfeed' => array('comment/feed', 'urlSuffix' => '.xml', 'caseSensitive' => false),
>         '/trackstar/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
>         '/trackstar/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
>         '/trackstar/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
>     ),
>     'showScriptName' => false,
> ),
> ```

Comment: No changes, still being redirected to `index.php`.

Comment: Same result, redirect to `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

.htaccess in root folder of project:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

IndexIgnore */*
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work; `http://localhost/trackstar/index.php/project` still works;
`http://localhost/trackstar/project` redirects to `localhost` (not even project root)

Comment: changed order of rule, can you try now.

Comment: Hmm, same result, a redirect to `localhost`.

Comment: With your last edit, I'm now being redirected to `index.php`.

Comment: So a URI like `http://localhost/trackstar/index.php` is not becoming `http://localhost/trackstar/`?

Comment: Indeed, I can access both URIs when I navigate to them. When I'm navigating to `http://localhost/trackstar/index.php`, the `index.php` part doesn't disappear.

Comment: `When I'm navigating to http://localhost/trackstar/index.php, the index.php part doesn't disappear.` That is fine then since `index.php` has been removed by my suggested rule above. Doesn't that solve your stated problem?

Comment: can you solve this issue 404 error
 'urlManager'=>array(
                              'urlFormat'=>'path',
                              'showScriptName'=>false,
                              'rules'=>array(
                                                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                                               '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                              '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                             ),
and

Comment: Htaccess 
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase  /
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: I want like this sitename/site/login

Comment: Don't write code in comments, post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with 2 simple steps.

1. Configure the 'urlManager' at config/main.php to look like this

   ```
           'urlManager'=>array(
               'urlFormat'=>'path',
               'showScriptName'=>false,      
           ),
   ```
2. Add an .htaccess file at the root of the application with the following code

   > ```
   > Options +FollowSymLinks
   > IndexIgnore */*
   > RewriteEngine on
   >
   > # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
   > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   >
   > # otherwise forward it to index.php
   > RewriteRule . index.php
   > ```

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

change your config/main.php like below:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```

then place your htaccess file on base directory with protected folder (it may be inside protected folder) place below code to your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

or try with this---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

done...hope it will work